# Adjuntar archivo en script para enviar correo en Python

Tags: python

Que código le puedo añadir a este script para poder  adjuntar un archivo y enviarlo al correo.
Gracias.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To= destino
mail.CC= copia
mail.Subject = 'Reporte impresiones '+mesa + ' '+fecha
mail.HTMLBody = 'Cordial saludo,' + '<br /><br />'
mail.HTMLBody = mail.HTMLBody + 'En la ruta '+ rutainf + ', se generó reporte con los siguientes datos:'+'<br /><br />'
mail.HTMLBody = mail.HTMLBody + l
mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizando **Attachments.Add**

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To= destino
mail.CC= copia
mail.Subject = 'Reporte impresiones '+mesa + ' '+fecha
mail.HTMLBody = 'Cordial saludo,' + '<br /><br />'
mail.HTMLBody = mail.HTMLBody + 'En la ruta '+ rutainf + ', se generó reporte con los siguientes datos:'+'<br /><br />'
mail.HTMLBody = mail.HTMLBody + l
mail.Attachments.Add(c:\temp\archivo.jpg)
mail.Send()
```

Recuerda que al agregar **Attachments.Add** debes colocar la ruta completa del archivo (por ejemplo, c:\temp\archivo.jpg), no solo un nombre de archivo.

Más info:
https://www.codeforests.com/2020/06/05/how-to-send-email-from-outlook/

Comment: Sabes cuales son las librearías que debo importar para que todo funcione

Comment: @HarlanEnciso debería ser **win32com.client**, he modificado mi respuesta para agregar el import.

Comment: Muchas gracias.